# How to specify cursive fonts in inline css

Tags: css, webfonts

A business user would like an input field in a Filebound web form to be in cursive. This is a  "signature" field - we understand that it is not legally necessary.

We can only use inline css to style the field, like so:

```
<input type="text" id="SingleLineText118" name="SigFieldTest" class="" style="width: 294px; height: 77px; font-family: 'Brush Script MT', 'Brush Script Std', cursive; font-size: 22px;" default-value="" value="">
```

My understanding is that we can list multiple font-families and the page checks each font in order and renders with the first one that the machine has, and if not then goes with the default font (FB will default to comic sans).

Is there a limit to how many families can be listed? Could I find the 5 most prevalent cursive fonts on both platforms and list 10 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in as many as you want. You’re only limited by how big of a document you want to send.